# error: expected primary-expression before 'char'

Tags: c++, char, boolean

Trying to call function `bool yes()` in `int main`. Keep getting the error shown above. Should I be including `char c` inside the function call?

```
bool yes(char c){ 
if(c == 'y' || c == 'Y'){
    return true;
}
else 
    return false;

}
int main(){
try{
char c;
cin>>c;
bool yes(char c); //not sure if char c should be here

    cout<<"Think of one of these 8 things: ..... Press '|' when you are ready\n";

if(c == '|'){
    cout<<"Are you thinking of something big?\n";
    cin>>c;

    if(yes(char c) == true){ //error here in yes(), trying to call function
        cout<<"Are you thinking of something that is alive?\n";
        cin>>c;
        if(yes(char c) == true){ //error here in yes(), trying to call function
            cout<<"Are you thinking of an animal?\n";
            cin>>c;

                 if(yes(char c) == true){ //error here in yes(), trying to call function
                    cout<<"You are thinking of an elephant.\n";

                    }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Read any tutorial of C++ and learn how to call a function. Hint: not like `yes(char c)`.

Comment: What is the purpose of `try`? Also, you don't need `== true` in the if statement.

Comment: To simplify things, delete this line: `bool yes(char c);` -- It serves no purpose in your example.

Comment: As has already been mentioned, your function call syntax is wrong. `if (yes(char c) == true)` should be `if (yes(c) == true)`. On top of that, comparing a `bool` value for equality to `false` or `true` is unnecessary. It's already a Boolean; just test it: `if (yes(c))`

Answer (score 0):

There are some minor semantic problems with how you're invoking your "yes" function. Try this:

```
bool yesResult = yes(c);
```

You're right about not including "char" when you invoke the method. It's no longer needed when you pass c to a function call -- c is inherently a char. One other thing to note is that in your first invocation of yes() you have "bool" specified before the call. Such syntax would only be necessary if you wanted to store the return value of the function, as in my example. Note that the type needs to be accompanied by a name. Your other invocations of yes() that are within if statement conditionals are perfectly fine as is.

Comment: As `c` keeps changing, assigning the result of `yes(c)` to a constant variable doesn't make sense. Just keep calling `yes(c)`.

Comment: Good point. I didn't read the rest of the code. The const keyword has been removed via edit.

Comment: The return value does not need to be stored in a variable.  It is fine to use it directly as in the OP's code.

Comment: Clearly it doesn't need to be. However, OP's first invocation of yes() appears to be a little confused in that it specifies a type before the invocation unnecessarily. My desire is to show OP when such syntax is valid. Every invocation of yes() after that point indeed does not need to be stored in a variable.

Comment: The first reference `bool yes(char c);` is not an invocation -- it is a prototype declaration of the function (and is redundant in that context).  I suggested that the OP remove it due to this very confusion.